# How do I pull values from one sheet to another, based on parameters?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet. I have tagged excel in case the solution would be the same, or if there is not solution at all I may consider excel.

I have a sheet with a list of names, and whether or not they are attending a weekly event of football.

The list of people is around 30 and we usually only get 10.

I'd like a way to be able to display only the people who are yes.

I have attached an image of my sheet.

I am thinking I would want to create another sheet and then pull through the only the values from column A where the corresponding value in AA = 'Yes'.

I am not sure where to start with this though.

Any ideas or can anyone point me in the right direction?

[image]

Comment: @Rubén fair enough and thanks for the link! i did try and look but i wasn't really sure how to word what i was looking for, so I tried to word the question like it would be easy to understand my problem  - could you give some advice on how i would have researched this specific question please? :)

Comment: It's fine to ask for help about how to ask for something but even in those cases you should show your research efforts. (Here is the link included in the previous comment : [ask])

Comment: You could use features like filters, filter views, tools like pivot table, the new explore tool, functions like FILTER, QUERY, use Google Apps Script... See http://support.google.com/docs (please note that it has a search tool)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this query on another sheet:

```
=query({Sheet1!A:A,Sheet1!AA:AA},"Select Col1 where Col2 ='Yes'")
```